Not able to decrypt pgp binary file with openpgp module
I have a openpgp binary file. I want to decrypt the file with openpgp node module and save the decrypted file in a folder. But when I am trying to run the code it does create the file but it can't be opened.
import * as openpgp from 'openpgp';
import fs from 'fs';

// Read the encrypted file
const encryptedData = fs.readFileSync(
  'D:\\Users\\test\\test.zip.pgp'
);

// Read the private key
const privateKeyArmored = fs.readFileSync(
  'D:\\Users\\test\\private.key.asc',
  'utf8'
);

const passphrase = 'your_passphrase';

// Decrypt the file
(async () => {
  try {
    const privateKey = await openpgp.decryptKey({
      privateKey: await openpgp.readPrivateKey({ armoredKey: privateKeyArmored }),
      passphrase
    });
    const { data: decryptedData } = await openpgp.decrypt({
      message: await openpgp.readMessage({ binaryMessage: encryptedData }),
      decryptionKeys: privateKey
      // password: passphrase
    });

    // Write the decrypted data to a new file
    fs.writeFileSync(
      'D:\\Users\\test\\test.zip',
      decryptedData
    );

    console.log('File decrypted successfully!');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error decrypting file:', error);
  }
})();

Output:
[OpenPGP.js debug] Error: Decryption error
at D:\Users\path\node_modules\openpgp\dist\node\openpgp.min.js:2:178461
at async Object.decrypt (D:\Users\path\node_modules\openpgp\dist\node\openpgp.min.js:2:177833)
at async ju.decrypt (D:\Users\path\node_modules\openpgp\dist\node\openpgp.min.js:2:291055)
at async D:\Users\path\node_modules\openpgp\dist\node\openpgp.min.js:2:345538
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at async D:\Users\path\node_modules\openpgp\dist\node\openpgp.min.js:2:344874
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at async D:\Users\path\node_modules\openpgp\dist\node\openpgp.min.js:2:344484
at async Promise.all (index 1)
at async Bh.decryptSessionKeys (D:\Users\path\node_modules\openpgp\dist\node\openpgp.min.js:2:344441)
File decrypted successfully!
So when the above code executes, it create a test.zip file in the folder but it says windows can not oben the folder.
Let me know if you have any solution to solve this.
Thanks.

you are not writing a binary file.
Try passing format: binary to the openpgp.decrypt options, otherwise UTF-8 (string) data is returned, and set the encoding option of writeFileSync to null. --From Github source
And it worked.
